# Next-i18next Initial locale argument was not passed into serverSideTranslations error in build mode (server)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

It worked in development mode (e.g yarn dev). But in build mode (e.g yarn build then yarn start) it doesn't work anymore. First thing in mind it must be have something todo with middleware.tsx. Becase the error is occured when i'm adding middleware.tsx.

Here is the middleware file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { evaluateFlags, randomSessionId } from "@unleash/nextjs";
import { addBasePath } from "next/dist/client/add-base-path";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  let cookies: any = req.cookies.get("flags");
  const newUrl = req.nextUrl.clone();
  const res = NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl);
  if (cookies) {
    return res;
  } else {
    const sessionId = req.cookies.get("flags")?.value || randomSessionId();
    const context = { sessionId };
    let flagCookies = null;

    // Grab definitions from an endpoint cached on the edge
    const protocol = req.url.startsWith("https") ? "https://" : "http://";
    const host = req.headers.get("host");
    const endpoint = addBasePath("/api/proxy-definitions");
    const token = process.env.UNLEASH_SERVER_INSTANCE_ID || "";
    const definitionsUrl = `${protocol}${host}${endpoint}?token=${token}`;

    // Make a request to the edge-cached endpoint
    const definitions = await fetch(definitionsUrl, { method: "GET" }).then(
      (res) => res.json()
    );

    // Evaluate based on provided context
    const evaluated = await evaluateFlags(definitions, context);
    flagCookies = JSON.stringify(evaluated);
    // Redirect to variant
    if (flagCookies)
      res.cookies.set("flags", flagCookies, {
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 1000)
      });
    return res;
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/:path*"]
};
```

Here is the next-i18next config :

```
module.exports = {
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "id",
    locales: ["id"]
  },
  reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
};
```

And here is _app.tsx

```
export function reportWebVitals(metric: NextWebVitalsMetric) {
  event(metric.name, {
    category:
      metric.label === "web-vital" ? "Web Vitals" : "Next.js custom metric",
    value: Math.round(
      metric.name === "CLS" ? metric.value * 1000 : metric.value
    ), // values must be integers
    label: metric.id, // id unique to current page load
    nonInteraction: true // avoids affecting bounce rate.
  });
}

const apm = initApm({
  serviceName: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ELASTIC_NAME || "service-name",
  serverUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ELASTIC_URL || "service-url",
  environment: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ELASTIC_ENVIRONTMENT || "env"
});

const enableApm = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APM_ENABLE === "true";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: any) {
  const { layout } = useLayout();
  const Layout = layout ? Component.layout || MainLayout : null;
  return (
    <LayoutProvider>
      <RootLayout>
        <Layout>
          <ToastContainer />
          <GoogleAnalytics />
          <OrgApmTransaction apm={enableApm ? apm : null}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </OrgApmTransaction>
        </Layout>
      </RootLayout>
    </LayoutProvider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

next-18next version : 12.1.0

Try : Access the app in build mode
Expected to happen : App worked properly
what actually resulted : Error: Initial locale argument was not passed into serverSideTranslations